# How can we trace axios http requests with aws x-ray?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-xray

I'm looking for a method to **trace axios http requests in my node.js based aws lambda function**. I've found a method to trace HTTP request on aws official docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-httpclients.html

```
var AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk');
var http = AWSXRay.captureHTTPs(require('http'));
```

But I didn't found any doc or blog regarding axios request tracing. 
I've tried this code as well, but it's not working.

```
import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal("../../common/http/HttpClient");
import { HttpClient } from "../../common/http/HttpClient";
```

I need help in this regards. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you elaborate more on "it's not working"? Are you getting any errors or the http info is simply missing? What is the syntax or code snippet you are using for making http calls using axios? Please note that the AWS X-Ray SDK for Nodejs doesn't officially support axios and you can see the patching code for the built-in http client here https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/blob/master/packages/core/lib/patchers/http_p.js

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting any error by adding these lines in my lambda function.

import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal("../../common/http/HttpClient");
import { HttpClient } from "../../common/http/HttpClient";

Actually in my lambda function I'm making an axios post request and testing an endpoint which returns 500 code. Ideally this error should be logged via aws x-ray but it's not logging the error.

But getting this message printed while deployment: "AWS_XRAY_CONTEXT_MISSING is set. Configured context missing strategy to LOG_ERROR"

Comment: @haotian465 I've just found a method to log axios errors using captureAsyncFunc but I'm wondering if I can convert it into promise so the code becomes cleaner. 

I've added the piece of code here: https://jsfiddle.net/zeeshantariq/1b68eLdr/77938/
But I'm getting error: Error: Param "fcn" must be a function.

Comment: this is in the backlog. You can open an issue here https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node or submit a PR for promisifying capture

Answer (score 22):

Since axios will use node's http/https modules under the covers, if you globally capture http and https before you import/require axios, things should work as expected.

```
import AWSXRay from 'aws-xray-sdk';
import http from 'http';
import https from 'https';

AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(http);
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(https);

const axios = require('axios');
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple example that should just work is

```
const
  axios = require('axios'),
  AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');

AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('http')); // Globally instrument http client
AWSXRay.captureHTTPsGlobal(require('https')); // Globally instrument https client

const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');

AWSXRay.capturePromise(); // We should capture promies
const instance = axios.create({
  httpAgent: new http.Agent(),
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent(),
}); // Instrument axious instance

const post = async (url, body) => {
  return await instance.post(url, body);
}
```

Make sure Lambda has correct acces rights.

Comment: this doesn't work, it says capturePromise is not a function. Where do these variables need to be declared? globally?